# Mysql UNION by date

Tags: mysql, union

I get problem with query Mysql. I have 2 tables like at picture , and I want get result like at picture too...

[image]
how the query with UNION ? thanks .. sorry for my english

Comment: Short and sweet. I like it. But what if tabel_a [sic] has '2014-08-14'? And do the ids always correspond?

Comment: As the answers below suggest, you cannot use `UNION` to merge columns from different tables, but only to append results.

Comment: Well, UNION *can* be a step in the right direction.

Comment: @Strawberry can you follow up on that ? I don't understand your comment.

Comment: @ovi As a first step, the OP is possibly looking for a FULL OUTER JOIN - a concept which can be emulated in MySQL by means of a UNION.

Comment: @Strawberry True, the question is vague.

Comment: all : thank you for having participated answer my question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get this result with a LEFT JOIN:

```
SELECT
    b.date_b as date_all,
    a.quota_a,
    b.quota_b
FROM
    tabel_b b
LEFT JOIN
    tabel_a a
ON
    a.id_a = b.id_b
```

You've got to take the date info from tabel_b, because else you get a NULL value for id = 4.

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fec942/1)

If tabel_a can have more rows than tabel_b too, then you've got to use a `FULL OUTER JOIN`. Because MySQL hasn't got inbuild FULL OUTER JOIN you can emulate this by a UNION of a `LEFT JOIN` and a `RIGHT JOIN`. And as Strawberry has pointed out, maybe is the equality of the id columns the result of simplification. I add therefor the equality of the date columns to the join condition:

Please regard that you've got to use `UNION`, not `UNION ALL` to get only distinct rows.

```
SELECT
    b.date_b as date_all,
    a.quota_a,
    b.quota_b
FROM
    tabel_b b
LEFT JOIN
    tabel_a a
ON
    a.id_a = b.id_b
AND
    a.date_a = b.date_b
UNION
SELECT
    b.date_b as date_all,
    a.quota_a,
    b.quota_b
FROM
    tabel_a a
LEFT JOIN
    tabel_b b
ON
    a.id_a = b.id_b
AND
    a.date_a = b.date_b
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fec942/2) (Note: with the sample data gets this the same result as the first one).

Comment: I suspect that the example is misleading in this respect. I think it highly unlikely that the ids correspond in the real world scenario - but I might be wrong!

Comment: @Strawberry I fear so too, it could be a full outer join too, but there's got to be another column beside the date, because joining only on the date column will lead to row duplication for '2014-08-15'

Answer (score 0):

if `date` is the parameter that "link" your tables [foreign key?] (from your answer title it seems), you could write the following query

```
SELECT date_a AS date_all, quota_a, quota_b
FROM tabel_B LEFT JOIN tabel_A ON date_a = date_b
ORDER BY date_all ASC
```

that way you'll obtain every record in `tabel_b`: if they have a corrispondence in `tabel_a`, either `date_a` and `date_b` will have a value, otherwise `date_a` will be `null`.
Please, pay attention: in that way you'll not obtain records that are present in `tabel_a` but not in `tabel_b`